# How to avoid/control a timezone offset when deploying next.js app to vercel?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, vercel, timezone-offset

In a React/Next.js App, is there a way to always make sure, anywhere in the world it shows the local time in CEST. Let’s say; I get the GMT time from my backend, which I want to offset, to display the CEST timezone offset of that time. That same time should be displayed anywhere in the world. Case: Exhibition Opening in Berlin at 6pm local time, shouldn't be displayed as different time in another timezone!
Important in my case is also, that it has to work as well if the server and client are in different timezones as the function may be called on either side. This was my attempt:

```
  const initialDate = new Date("Fri, 07 May 2021 17:00:00 GMT");

  const userTimezoneOffset = initialDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;

  const date = new Date(initialDate.getTime() - userTimezoneOffset);
```

I am struggling to fix this one for a while now, and I failed to find a solution working for me. When the app is deployed, it is 4pm instead of 6pm. It works correctly in dev mode as well as when building locally, it even works when I change my local time with .env.TZ. But the timezone is always off when deploying to vercel. I assume it has something to do, wether the time is rendered server-side or client-side…

Comment: use common day format , try to use moment.js

Comment: Tried that as well and it didn't solve the problem!
Same timeoffset!

Comment: @Vijay - Moment has been retired.  Per https://stackoverflow.com/tags/momentjs/info, please refrain from recommending Moment as a solution unless Moment is specifically asked for in the question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

- CEST is UTC+2, and was indeed in effect in Berlin on the date you gave - so 6pm (18:00) is 16:00 UTC, not 17:00 UTC.
- You should prefer date strings in ISO 8601 / RFC 3339 format, rather than the RFC 822/2822 formatted string you showed.  (See [the language spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date.parse) for how dates get parsed.)
- The approach you show that is subtracting time from the date object and constructing a new one should be avoided.  You're not actually changing the time zone, but picking a new point in time completely.
- `Date` objects cannot *represent* time in other time zones, but they can create string representations that have a time zone applied by using `toLocaleString` and specifying the `timeZone` option.

Thus, you can do this:

```js
const d = new Date("2021-05-07T16:00:00Z");
const s = d.toLocaleString(undefined, {timeZone: 'Europe/Berlin' });
console.log(s);
```

Note `undefined` here means to use the user's default locale (language and region-specific formatting preferences) to produce an appropriate string.  You could instead specify a language such as `en` or full locale such as `en-US`.  There are also many other formatting options available.  See [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) for details.

Answer (score 0):

i found two options so far

A) use `date-fns-tz`s format function and hardcode your timezone. this could be problematic though. i like the rule that anything on the server is always UTC.

```
const date = format(new Date(startDate), "do MMM yy", {
  timeZone: "Europe/Vienna",
});
```

B) always render dates in client components (my preferred option)

this ensures that dates are always displayed in the clients timezone. so no matter where your user is located, they see the date correctly calculated for their timezone.

```
"use client";
import { formatTrainingDate } from "@/lib/date";

export function TrainingDate({ start, end }: { start: Date; end: Date }) {
  return <>{formatTrainingDate(start, end)}</>;
}
```